# How can I find a finite closed form for $\phi (\lambda)$?

Tags: summation, closed-form, infinity

How can I find a finite closed form for $\phi (\lambda)$, which that

> $$\lim_{\lambda \to \infty} \frac{\sum_{n=1}^{\lambda}2^{n^2}}{\phi(\lambda)}=1~~~~~~~~\lambda \in \mathbb{Z^{+}}$$

Is this mathematically possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $2^{n^2}$ increases so quickly, the sum is essentially  just the last term and you can take $\phi(\lambda)=2^{\lambda^2}$.  In more detail,
$$\frac{\sum_{n=1}^\lambda 2^{n^2}}{2^{\lambda^2}}
  =1+\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{\lambda-1} 2^{n^2}}{2^{\lambda^2}}
  \le1+\frac{\lambda2^{(\lambda-1)^2}}{2^{\lambda^2}}
  =1+\frac{2\lambda}{2^{2\lambda}}$$
which tends to $1$ as $\lambda\to\infty$.  The left hand side is clearly at least $1$, so by the squeeze theorem it also tends to $1$ as $\lambda\to\infty$.